# Select the containing <tr> of a $(this) element

Tags: jquery

How would I go about finding the containing `<tr>` of an element in question through jQuery?

i.e. I click a button within a table cell, and want the row to gain a class too.

```
$(".disable-all").click(function() {

    $(this).addClass("disabled");

    $(table-row-containing-this-button).addClass("disable-me-too"); // What goes here?

});
```

Is it then possible to access any other buttons **within** that `<tr>`, e.g. in the same level of hierarchy as `.disable-all`?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <button class="disable-all"></button>
        <button class="dont-forget-me"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) :

```
$(this).addClass("disabled").closest('tr').addClass("disable-me-too");
```

If it's the same class you want to add to both elements, there's a DRYer way :

```
$(this).closest('tr').addBack().addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: That's a phenomenally quick answer, thank you. Will accept as soon as I can!